# Does firebug have psychic powers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, firebug

How did firebug know, that I was about to invoke map on an array of number?

[image]

**Note**

On a machine with freshly installed firebug, the behavior is consistent. As few people have noted, it is not trying to remember my usual pattern of usage.

Comment: @AdamRackis, Yes but not in this particular format though. I generally call on a jQuery Object Array.

Comment: @closevoter: Can you please help me understand as to which part of the question is unclear or how can I improve it?

Comment: It's possible that it's just jumping to somewhere near the middle of the list. When I use the example you provide, it also jumps to `.map` (which I've hardly used in Firebug at all), with exactly the same number of options before and after it. For shorter lists (~10 items) it doesn't do this, and for the much longer list due to `$.` it's jumps near the middle, but not directly at it.

Comment: Hah, I was the one who implemented this in Firebug. The "magic" algorithm is: default to the auto-completion with the shortest name. Generally it works pretty well.

Comment: @SimonLindholm: And I guess you can post this as an answer?

Comment: @SimonLindholm When you post that as answer - and when it's an answer, you should always post it as such - you could maybe also point the people to the place in the code where that happens.

Comment: I can post it as an answer if the question leaves the "put on hold as unclear" state.

Comment: This is a +1 just for the name.